# Using jquery toggle() inside a custom polymer element

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I want to use a button to toggle a word on click like this:

```js
function toggle() {
    $("#secret").toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <button onClick="toggle()"> toggle </button>
    <p id="secret" style="display: none"> secret </p>
</body>
```

This works without problems but when using the code inside a custom Polymer element, the word is only shown but not hidden again.

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="test-element">
    <template>
        <button on-tap="{{toggle}}"> toggle </button>
        <p id="secret" style="display: none"> secret </p>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            toggle: function() {
                $(this.$.secret).toggle();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<test-element></test-element>
```

However, using `show()` and `hide()` works:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="test-element">
    <template>
        <button on-tap="{{toggle}}"> Toggle </button>
        <p id="secret"> secret </p>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            toggle: function() {
                if ($(this.$.secret).css("display") == "block") {
                    $(this.$.secret).hide();
                } else {
                    $(this.$.secret).show();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<test-element></test-element>
```

Why is the `toggle()` function working itself but not working inside a custom polymer element when `show()` and `hide()` are working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think jquery works inside polymer elements. and if so maybe not fully working. but it's easy to fix. you could use https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-collapse

Comment: The main problem was with the function `slideToggle()` but I noted this behaviour also with `toggle()`. I ended up using `show()` and `hide()`  but I was just wondering about this behaviour because most jquery functions worked inside polymer elements and I haven't read anything about this problem.
However, if you know any solution for `slideToggle()`, let me know because I really would like to have an animation instead.

Comment: i understand. just offering you a "Polymer" method for doing what you are trying to do. which might be faster to get going and known to work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have to use jQuery for "toggling" you can do that in more polymeric way:

```html
<script src="//www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="test-element">
  <template>
    <button on-tap="{{toggle}}">Toggle</button>
    <p id="secret" hidden?="{{!showingSecret}}">secret</p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      toggle: function() {
        this.showingSecret = !this.showingSecret;
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<test-element></test-element>
```